# Docker volume bind is not working with current directory

Tags: docker, bind, ubuntu-20.04

I am Docker 20.10.17, build 100c701. Whenever I bind a local directory to a volume it doesn't show the volume using `ls`.

```
(base) hell@Dell-Precision-T7910:~/Desktop/PhD/PHD/Nvidia Modulus/Modulus v22.03$ pwd
/home/hell/Desktop/PhD/PHD/Nvidia Modulus/Modulus v22.03
(base) hell@Dell-Precision-T7910:~/Desktop/PhD/PHD/Nvidia Modulus/Modulus v22.03$ ls
'Key features.txt'   Modulus_examples   Modulus_examples.tar.gz   modulus_image_v22.03.tar.gz   Modulus_source   Modulus_source.tar.gz
(base) hell@Dell-Precision-T7910:~/Desktop/PhD/PHD/Nvidia Modulus/Modulus v22.03$ docker run --gpus all --ipc=host --ulimit memlock=-1 --ulimit stack=67108864 -v ${pwd}:/examples -it modulus:22.03 bash

=============
== PyTorch ==
=============
root@b880211ba2ca:/examples# ls -a
.  ..
root@b880211ba2ca:/examples# ls
```

My `pwd` contains spaces and uppercase, I don't think there should a problem with spaces.

However, when I bind `/home/` it works fine.

```
(base) hell@Dell-Precision-T7910:~/Desktop/PhD/PHD/Nvidia Modulus/Modulus v22.03$ docker run --gpus all --ipc=host --ulimit memlock=-1 --ulimit stack=67108864 -v /home/hell/:/examples -it modulus:22.03 bash

=============
== PyTorch ==
=============
root@67b5dbfa0e10:/examples# ls
'2022-06-10 09-50-30.mkv'  '2022-06-10 10-02-08.mkv'  '2022-06-11 01-54-01.mkv'   Documents   MATLAB   Pictures   Templates        Videos            Zotero      libreoffice
'2022-06-10 09-59-18.mkv'  '2022-06-11 01-51-17.mkv'   Desktop                    Downloads   Music    Public     Untitled.ipynb  'VirtualBox VMs'   anaconda3   snap
root@67b5dbfa0e10:/examples#
```

Please help me. BTW I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with RTX A5000 24GB.

Comment: Do you mean `"${PWD}:/examples"`, using capital `PWD` as the environment variable name, and surrounded with double quotes?  Or `"$(pwd):/examples"` to use the output of the `pwd` command?  If the current directory name includes spaces then the double quotes are required.

Comment: Oh I didn't knew it should be `$(pwd)` not `${pwd}`. Thanks a lot it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your command uses `-v ${pwd}:/examples`, the syntax `${pwd}` expands to an environment variable named `pwd`.  This probably expands to an empty string; you either need the environment variable `PWD` (all uppercase, the case matters) or the output of the shell command `pwd`.  You say the path includes spaces; this makes it important to put the argument in double-quotes as well.

```bash
# using the $PWD environment variable
docker run -v "${PWD}:/example" ...

# using the `pwd` command
docker run -v "$(pwd):/example" ...
```